# Диагональ экрана Android-устройства

Tags: android

Всем доброго утра. Преподаватель дал задание программно найти диагональ экрана.
Нашла код на этом форуме, но он считает неточно.

Например мой телефон с диагональю 5 дюймов, считает как 4.834685856410803.

Что сделать, чтобы расчеты стали точны?

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
Log.d("", "Диагональ моего телефона : " + screenInches);
```

Comment: Округлить? `Math.round(screenInches)`

Answer (score 4):

> Например мой телефон с диагональю 5 дюймов, считает как 4.834685856410803.

А вы померяйте, только точно... причём именно изображение на матрице, а не саму матрицу (ведь считаете Вы размер именно для изображения) - рискуете удивиться.

Это маркетинг...

Comment: Я запуталась. Берем значение 4.834685856410803 переводим в сантиметры и получаем 10,160000000000000142.Блин, ну, какие 10см!!! Далее беру школьную линейку, меряю 12.7 см. =5 дюймов. Akina подскажите, где я затупила. Я понимаю что меряла саму матрицу, а Вы изображение на ней, как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит как? изображение на экране до противности прямоугольное - вот и меряйте от левого верхнего пиксела до правого нижнего. Ну или по другой диагонали - без разницы. `Берем значение 4.834685856410803 переводим в сантиметры и получаем 10,160000000000000142` - а Вы где живёте? у Вас там сколько сантиметров в дюйме-то? у нас вот дюйм - это 2,54 см...